# GameKit keeping connection going while device screen off or in background

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I am working on an appliction that requires bluetooth connectivity, which i use GameKit for data transfer, however im seeing that when i go in background mode, or I just turn off the screen in app, the bluetooth connection is dropped... Ive seen other apps that keep the connection alive in such situations, anyone have any idea if I am missing something that wont cause the connection to drop on such cases? Have been looking around but havent found anything useful...

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I discover other iOS devices over Bluetooth while in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204080/can-i-discover-other-ios-devices-over-bluetooth-while-in-the-background)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not intentionally supported by Apple.

If you are writing this for an application that doesn't have to be distributed through the App Store, you can set the application up to play a silent audio file in the background.  This will allow GameKit to continue to work even when your application has been put into the background or if the screen has locked.

If this application has to be distributed through the App Store, Apple require the audio to be a real feature, with audible music playing.

Comment: Seems like apps in the AppStore use this aproach tho, music playing apps.. Which mine is so o might be in luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have two devices connected using GKSession and then one of them is interrupted by call or goes into background, when it wakes up connection should be still alive (you should be able to send/receive packets between devices).

You may try setting

[UIRequiresPersistentWiFi](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

in your plist.