# Since I updated iOS5,when My device sleep, gamekit bluetooth's disconnected

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm making bluetooth multi play game using cocos2d, game kit bluetooth.
but since I updated iOS5, when my device sleep or pressed home button, my bluetooth connection was disconnected.
Does anyone know this problem?

Before I updated iOS5, It works well.

Even My brother's iPhone 4 which has iOS4 works well. I'm sure It's iOS5's problem. or there is some option for game kit bluetooth...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi There I found this answer here for you:
[Keeping Connection Alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003951/gamekit-keeping-connection-going-while-device-screen-off-or-in-background)

look @ the non accepted answer they say to use [UIRequiresPersistentWiFi](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

But for you a better open would be `UIBackgroundModes` in conjunction with a value of `external-accessory`

I Hope this helps =D