# How to run the iOS App when screen is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, nsurlconnection

I am downloading some files from server using NSURLConnection. It works fine when app is in foreground or background. App is not running when iPhone Screen is locked.
My client want the App to run in locked mode also. Is there any way to download the data when screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

you can not test application when device is locked

check this apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your app will be rejected by Apple if you turn app on screen locked.

Refer to these links which answered already:

[GameKit keeping connection going while device screen off or in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003951/gamekit-keeping-connection-going-while-device-screen-off-or-in-background)

[Running IOS App with Screen Locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314869/running-ios-app-with-screen-locked)